# Iphone simulator 4.0 Could not find my current location

Tags: iphone

I installed sdk version 4.0 in mac my friend also installed version 4.0 in his mac.In my iphone simulator 4.0 ,it could find current location.But my friend machine iphone simulator 4.0 had find the current location.

What is the problem ? we both connected with wifi network.Both mac machine having ability to find current location.But there is difference in iphone simulator 4.0.

Plz help me ? I really need this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when I updated to the iOS 4 SDK I had to enable my AirPort wireless and connected to a wireless network to actually get a fix on my location. It appears that Apple is using your wifi access point to pinpoint your location now. I noticed you mentioned you are connected to wifi though, which seems a bit odd. That is the only case I've come across in a couple years of developing using the simulator.